# Problem not reading GET in frindly url in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If you look at the YouTube site when you search, you will see that there is a URL result and then method.

For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=s
```

My `.htaccess` file code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteRule  post/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule post/(.*) index.php?id=$1
```

I want to put `post/122` on that page for paging, for example, and I want method to be added here.

But this is where the new problem begins. Because the Get function is no longer read.

URLs are tests !!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What URL are you going to and what do you want to happen?

Comment: You need to use the correct terminology when describing the URL. What I think you are describing as the "URL result" is the URL-path and the "method" is the query string, or more specifically a URL parameter in the query string. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need the `QSA` flag for the rewrite rule then it will append the original query string into the new uri

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteRule  post/(.*)/ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule post/(.*) index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule